# For loop break doesn't work Python

Tags: python, for-loop, break

I'm starting to code in python for one of my lectures and I want to break my for loop but it doesn't happends.

```
NumberOfSpikes = []
for x in range(0, 10):        

  NumberOfSpikes[x] = format(spike_monitor.count[0])
  print (0.1*x)
  print(NumberOfSpikes[x])
  if (NumberOfSpikes[x] == 1):        
    break
```

> {0.0
>   0
>   0.1
>   0
>   0.2
>   0
>   0.3
>   0
>   0.4
>   0
>   0.5
>   ***1***
>   0.6
>   3
>   0.7
>   4
>   0.8
>   5
>   0.9
>   6}

So this is my output and we see that when the condition is met `NumberOfSpikes[x] = 1` the for loop doesn't stop. could somebody tell me why?

Comment: `format` returns a string, and you're comparing that string to the integer 1.

Comment: Ok my mistake is that NumberOfSpikes[x] = format(spike_monitor.count[0]) stores in NumberOfSpikes as if it was a string because of the format and then the condition if (NumberOfSpikes[x] == 1) is never met because I compare a string or a character with an integer.

Comment: Yes, I realized just now! thanks :)